# OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY breaks VS2019 database project build

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, database-project

I need to set OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON for several of my PKs on tables in Azure SQL Databases.

Running the code in SSMS against Azure SQL works perfectly, as expected.  But, when I add the text for this index option into my database project in VS 2019 (16.6.2), I get the following error:

SQL71627: The element Primary Key: [dbo].[PK_UserActions] has property DoOptimizeForSequentialKey set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

This VS error is invalid since this option *is* valid/allowed/supported in Azure SQL (according to official documentation and actual functional validation), and it works perfectly in all my instances (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8).  But, I cannot find a way to suppress this bogus error so I can build and publish my DACPACs.

An old SO answer said to target the project to "SQL Server 2019 and Azure SQL", but this no longer exists.  The only other target platform beyond "Microsoft Azure SQL Database" is "SQL Server 2019 and Azure SQL Database Managed Instance".  When selecting the latter target platform, the VS project builds properly.

But, I am not targeting a Managed Instance, so I am concerned about having to use a bogus target platform to get around an obvious VS2019 compiler error.

Am I justified in being concerned here, or should I just target the wrong platform which builds and hope for the best, or is there some non-kludge way to make this work properly?  I've tried all suppression techniques to ignore the error on build, but nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  This is a SSDT issue.  And it belongs on the SQL Server feedback site: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server

Comment: Thank you.  I will be sure to add it there as well.

Comment: @JeffRamos did you get any progresses? You can post something as an answer.

Comment: @LeonYue I have open tickets with Microsoft, but have not heard anything back.  It's just a waiting game at this point.  There is no answer to post.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have still not received a response from MS regarding this issue I reported, but your comment is the best info provided.  Please post your comment as an answer, and I will close this question out accordingly.  Thanks!